# How to stop of running the keycodes 37 and 39 when there is a textarea selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simply I have a js script that change the page with left and right arrows, but how to stop that if a specific textarea is selected ?

This is my js to change the page

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {

    if(event.keyCode === 37) {
          window.location = "http://site.com/pics/5";
    }    
    else if(event.keyCode === 39) {
          window.location = "http://site.com/pics/7";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest approach is to factor `event.target` into your code, checking to see if it is the textarea:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.target.id == "myTextArea") {
        return true;
    }
    else if(event.keyCode === 37) {
        window.location = "http://site.com/pics/5";
    }    
    else if(event.keyCode === 39) {
        window.location = "http://site.com/pics/7";
    }
});
```

Any key events that originate from a `textarea` element with an id of *myTextArea* will then be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('textarea').on('keypress', function(evt) {
  if ((evt.keyCode === 37) || (evt.keyCode === 39)) {
     console.log('stop propagation');
     evt.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

See example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GUDqV/1

Update: after OP clarification this works even on jQuery 1.2.6 on Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/GUDqV/2/

```
$('textarea').bind('keyup', function(evt) {
  if ((evt.keyCode === 37) || (evt.keyCode === 39)) {
     console.log('stop propagation');
     evt.stopPropagation();
  } 
});​
```

see screenshot of this code on Chrome and jQ1.2.6 [image: latest code on Chrome and jQ1.2.6]

Comment: For some reason the code dosent work. In google chrome debugging tool it shows Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL for line 80 witch is }); from your code

Comment: another error Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on' . And i'm using jquery 1.4.2

Comment: well, on() method works since jQuery 1.7 (that's the version lib I used). Use bind() instead. Please, next time specify which version you're using in the question itself, especially if it's not the latest

Comment: Well again the code dosent work. In the console its show 'stop propagation' but still is changing the page

Comment: see my update. I used jQuery 1.2.6 and it works fine again (on chrome 18)

Comment: I switch to 1.7 , but still is dosent work. I upadte my question and add a sample code. I dont know where to put your code

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the textarea is in focus by doing something like:

```
if (document.activeElement == myTextArea) {
  // Don't change the page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#mytextarea").is(":focus")` This will let you know if the element is focused. 
Also `$(document.activeElement)` will get the currently focused element.
You can check to see if your text area is focused, and disable the script that navigates when using left and right arrow keys.
A little bit of code showing what you've tried might bring in more specific responses.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I try if($("#mytextarea").is(":focus")){}
else
{ // the left and right code } but that dosent work